# Can PDFBox load a source PDF once then save multiple, variable page ranges as individual PDFs?

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I am writing a system that is processing very large PDFs, up to 400,000 pages with 100,000 individual statements per PDF. My task is to quickly split this PDF up into individual statements. This is made complicated by the fact that the statements vary in page count so I can't do a simple split on every 4th page.

I'm using parallel processing on a 36 core AWS instance to speed up the job but doing an initial split of a 400,000 page PDF into 36 chunks is very, very, slow, although processing the resulting 11,108 page chunks is very quick, so there's a lot of overhead for a good result in the end.

The way I think this could be done even faster would be to write a process using PDFBox that loads the source PDF into memory one time (versus calling commandline utilities like pdftk or cpdf 36 times to split the massive PDF) then have it listen on a port for the children of my other process to tell it to split pages x-y into a pdf named z.

Is this possible with PDFBox and if so what methods would I use to accomplish it?

Comment: I wonder if PDFBox can load a file with 400000 pages, even with a scratch file. However PDFBox is not thread-safe: https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/faq.html#threadsafe

Comment: @TilmanHausherr: In the case I'm considering, it would be one process accessing the PDF but listening for commands from other processes over a socket. Of course, if it can't even open the file in the first place this is a non-starter.

Comment: The problem is you can't pass the PDDocument object to your other processes. It must all be done in one thread. Re opening the file, try it. https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#load%28java.io.File,%20org.apache.pdfbox.io.MemoryUsageSetting%29

Comment: What makes @Tilman fear that already opening might be an issue, is that PdfBox holds much (all?) of the pdf in memory after loading. Pdfs with 400000 pages might mean pretty huge resource requirements.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr: I don't want to pass a PDDocument object to my other processes. I'm asking if there's a method for saving pages x-y to a new PDF named z in PDFBox that I can call through a socket. Only one process will be loading the source PDF file and nothing will be returned, just a file created. Is that something PDFBox can do? I looked through the methods but didn't see anything. Even the command line PDFSplit doesn't say where it takes a destination path for the new PDF. Do you pipe the return content or something?

Comment: @user1666112 You can create new PDDocument objects from existing pages of another PDDocument with the Splitter class. You can save a PDDocument to an OutputStream. https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#save%28java.io.OutputStream%29